# Inserting a shortcode to render a form in a custom built website

Tags: web-development, cms

I'm putting together a specification to built a custom site, it will incorporate amongst other things a form and number of pages. However when built there should be little need to create further pages or add additional forms.

Looking around at a few CMS's I noted they use a modular approach. i.e. Some build a forms widget and a shortcode is added on the CMS page to insert the form etc.

When it comes to custom builds is this the standard approach or is this specifically for a CMS built that is generalised to offer flexibility so it appeals to many users.(i.e Wordpress)

Is this approach still current and should it be something I should consider if I am creating a tailored site for my needs?